# What am I - An enigmatic haiku

Tags: poetry

> I'm part of a whole
>
> Re-united we are none
>
> Something yet nothing

What am I?

Comment: This is my first post on Puzzling StackExchange. Constructive criticisms are gladly welcomed.

Comment: I have a feeling this is too broad, I already have 3 or 4 answers in my mind...

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I added another line. I hope it helps. It is related to the first line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Gonna give it a try:

> Antimatter

Because:

> Its part of the whole universe, reunited with matter both dissapear, it is both something and an origin for nothingness

Comment: Right on. That's what I was thinking about.

Comment: If that's the answer, then "Re-united we are none" really bothers me. Upon annihilation, all of the mass energy from the two particles still exists, it's just in a different form. And a form that could reform back into a particle/anti-particle pair upon scattering.

Comment: I gave that answer coz I believed literally nothing exists after the union. Would you happen to know if the physics knowledge about this has changed in the past years? Anyway I find the quote correct, for the particles emselves are none afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

I guess you are

> a semi-circle

Because

I'm part of a whole

> more specifically, half of one

Re-united we are none

> With the other half, you form a circle, or $0$

Something yet nothing

> A semi-circle is something as it is a shape, but it is also nothing as it has no basis in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, I think this is too broad, so here it is:

> Planet Earth

Explanation:

> Part of a whole galaxy
>  Permeating in a void
>  It's something, yet nothing in the vast universe

Comment: You are looking from the right "scale". Please have a look at the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

> There can be uncountable number of answers.
> Any set of numbers with sum of zero checks out.
> Example: $\{1, -1, 2, -2, \pi, -\pi\}$
>
> ```
> Part other whole = part of the set.
> Together cancels out into zero.
> Numbers are abstract concepts so they are nothing.
> ```

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling SE! I have added a spoiler tag to your answer using `>!`.